# using $.each to addClass to elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to style a sub-set of anchors using an array

HTML & CSS:

```
<div>
    <a href="#1">one</a>
    <a href="#2">two</a>
    <a href="#3">three</a>
    <a href="#4">four</a>
    <a href="#5">five</a>
    <a href="#6">six</a>
    <a href="#7">seven</a>   
</div>

.hilight {
    background: #f00;
}
```

e.g. how would I add the class 'hilight' to anchors 2, 5, & 6...

Having tested this:

```
$("a[href='#5']").addClass('hilite');
```

I tried the the following with $.each(), which doesn't work. I guess I'm iterating over each anchor 3 times, but I didn't expect NO output!

```
var arr = ["#2", "#5", "#6"];   
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    $("a[href=value]").addClass('hilite');'
});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please :)

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't work because `$("a[href=value]")` doesn't exist.

You wan to use `$("a[href='"+value+"']")` instead, where value will be "replace" by the value of the variable value.

Here a fix:

```
var arr = ["#2", "#5", "#6"];   
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    $("a[href='"+value+"']").addClass('hilite');
});
```

Comment: Why traverse the DOM searching for `a[href='" + value + "']"` for each value in the array.  It is not necessary.

Comment: What do you think `$("a[href='#2'], a[href='#5'], a[href='#6']")` is doing ?

Comment: What `$("a[href='#2'], a[href='#5'], a[href='#6']")` is doing is, it starts at the top of the DOM and begins Traversing storing all elements that match in a jQuery Object (Traverses the DOM once.)  if you split it up into separate statements, such as `$("a[href='"+value+"']")` it will traverse the DOM from top to bottom for each statement.

Comment: John is correct! The multi selector will traverse the DOM only once.

Answer (score 4):

You dont need each at all, you can just use all selectors separated by commas.

```
$("a[href='#2'], a[href='#5'], a[href='#6']").addClass('hilite');
```

Comment: This is more efficient than @zzarbi answer however it is less dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a TON of them, it might be simpler to just do...

```
$("a[href='#2'], a[href='#5'], a[href='#6']").addClass('hilite');
```

To do the same thing, but more dynamically (for John)...

```
var arr = ["#2", "#5", "#6"]; 
$("a[href='"+arr.join("'], a[href='")+"']").addClass('hilite');
```

This assumes that `arr` always has at least one element.

Comment: This is more efficient than @zzarbi answer however it is less dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method has the ability to create a function to determine what class to add.  You can use this to determine if the element is a one that needs the class added.  This would be more efficient than running the selector `$("a[href='"+value+"']")` for each value in the array as it would only traverse the DOM once instead of n(size of the array) times.

```
var arr = ["#2", "#5", "#6"];  

$("a").addClass(function () {
  if (arr.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) != -1) {
    return "hilight";
  }
});
```

Here is a demonstration
http://jsfiddle.net/VqLnt/3/

I also want to note that your CSS class is named `hilight` but the class you are trying to add in JavaScript is `hilite`.  This is probably a typo but just want you to be aware.

Comment: @bart - thanks for this (and noting the typo) - the intention is to fill the array dynamically, so I guess my question was incomplete! Not easy being a designer that's now hooked on JS & jQuery... :)

Comment: @Mudimo Okondo ...Not a problem but I am not bart